# Set default activeClassName for NavLink in React Router v4

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

Is there a way to set a default `activeClassName` for `NavLink` in **React Router v4** instead of having to set it for each `NavLink`?

```
<NavLink activeClassName='active' to='/one/'>one</NavLink>
<NavLink activeClassName='active' to='/two/'>two</NavLink>
<NavLink activeClassName='active' to='/three/'>three</NavLink>
```

It would be nice to just write:

```
<NavLink to='/one/'>one</NavLink>
<NavLink to='/two/'>two</NavLink>
<NavLink to='/three/'>three</NavLink>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a wrapper?

```
const MyNavLink = ({ children, ...props }) => (
  <NavLink activeClassName="active" {...props}>
    {children}
  </NavLink>
);

<MyNavLink to='/one/'>one</MyNavLink>
```